# Digital repository software for PDF files

Tags: web-apps, file-management, information-management

I am looking for an archiving repository, or digital library, to use for storing and retrieving PDF files.

More precisely, I am interested in creating this repository for the library of a medium-sized private school, to store the various assignments students undertake during their projects.

As I imagine, students will their assignment files in various formats via email and they will be uploaded, along with basic metadata, to this system. It is required to have a web UI, a search text-box, basic filtering, to be able to search for files, according to keywords, subjects, and so on.

Proposals should include specialized software. Free or open source software proposals are welcome as well.

See for example https://repository.kallipos.gr/?&locale=en, but for smaller scale.